# Alguém já usou a AdMob no Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight e funcionou?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1

Eu tenho um aplicativo concluído e eu gostaria de publicar, mas eu tenho medo de ter que refazer o projeto no Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight. Atualmente estou tendo problema em admob onde o emulador funciona e o dispositivo dá a mensagem "nofill". Alguém sabe me dizer se eu publicar vai funcionar? Eu já publiquei no BETA para teste e também não funcionou, dava a mesma mensagem de erro.

A documentação do AdMob explica que ele funciona no Windows Phone 8 e mais recentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesmo bastante tempo depois. Sim, o AdMob só não funciona no Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime (WinRT).
Eu aconselho a usar o Ad Mediator, para poder incluir outras redes de anúncios no seu app.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/401703a0-263e-4949-8f0f-738305d6ef4b

Eu o utilizo e funciona muito bem. Atualmente utilizo o pubCenter e o Adduplex como backup.